# If $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ then $Y$ is a ... of $X$?

Tags: terminology

This is more of a linguistic question than a mathematical one, but let me try anyway:

> What is the antonym of *subspace*?

Is it a *superspace*? What else?

Suppose $X$ is a subspace of $Y$, say, a topological space, a vector space or whatever other spaces there are in mathematics. What is then $Y$ in relation to $X$?

Comment: How modest of you not to propose "hyperspace" :)

Comment: "Superspace" is probably a bad idea; "super" already has connotations coming from supersymmetry (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold).

Comment: I'd go with _ambient space_, and wikipedia supports that opinion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_space - anyway, I've never really seen someone use this term.

Comment: @roman Would be be interested in posting some variation of your comment as an answer, so that this no longer remains on the unanswered page?

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a subspace of $Y$, then $Y$ is usually called the [ambient space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_space) of $X$.